# How to replace all instances of /N with NaN in a csv file using Python

Tags: python

I've read a csv file into Python, and it contains many objects for which the value is \N. I need to replace all of those instances with 'NaN'.

I've gotten the file to read in correctly, but I get an error when I try to replace the \Ns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv')

df.replace('\N', 'NaN')

File "<ipython-input-63-a631ab1f5217>", line 3
    df.replace('\N', 'NaN')
              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: malformed \N character escape
```

Comment: is that a typo or do you have a `r` before the path to your csv-file? Also maybe use `np.nan` instead of `'NaN'`

Comment: if it's really `\N`, use replace(`\\N` ?

Comment: adding the extra backslash worked thank you!

Comment: [pandas read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) accepts a parameter called `na_values` which can be used to set any string as NaN directly when reading the file. You could do: `df = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv', na_values='\N')` (or `\\N` again) and drop the `df.replace` call.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses backslashes as a symbol to signify [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) like newlines, tabs, quotes, etc. So if you want to use backslashes in a string, you must replace all the single backslashes with double backslashes, like so;

```py
df.replace('\\N', 'NaN')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `na_values="\\N"` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',na_values="\\N")
```

Double backslash should be used to escape backslash.